# how to use jq command to create a table from a file content

Tags: command-line

I already used grep sed command to do something (`cat service.yaml |  grep -Po '(service_[^:]*|version:.+)'| sed -z 's/\nversion//g'`), but now I need to create a "table" of content of this file in the output like this:

Comment: Which `yq` are you using? The Go version or the Python version? Post output of `yq --version`

Comment: @Inian yq version 3.3.2

Comment: Note that mikefarah yq (https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) - has no direct way to manipulate results in a tabular format like what you have. There is one other version of yq you can use - https://github.com/kislyuk/yq which can uses `jq` underneath, which can put results in custom csv or tsv formats

Comment: @Inian what do you mean, what's the difference btw 2 links you forwarded? you mean there's two types of yq commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a variant of @jq170727's solution that only uses:

1. a yaml-to-json translator; and
2. jq

To illustrate an alternative to yq for (1), I'll use npm's `yaml2json`.

```
yaml2json service.yaml | jq -r '
  keys_unsorted as $keys
  | (["service", "version", "replica"] | map("\"\(.)\"")),    # quote the headers
    ($keys[] as $k | .[$k] | [$k, .version, .replica])
  | @tsv'
```

Notice also that `keys_unsorted` is used, mainly to respect the order of the keys in the original YAML file.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but as I mentioned before, we have 2 kind of yq cmd which are made by different persons, both your answer and @jq170727 's solutions are related to this: https://github.com/kislyuk/yq which use different version to the version that I'm using (I'm using: https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/ ) so unfortunately your cmd doesn't work for me

Comment: My specific answer avoids yq precisely for that reason, but you can substitute any other yaml-to-json translator you like.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a filter which may help

```
keys[] as $k | .[$k] | [$k, .version, .replica]
```

Here is an example using it.  For reference this is the yq I have from brew

```
$ yq --help | grep github
See https://github.com/kislyuk/yq for more information.
and/or https://stedolan.github.io/jq
```

First convert yaml to json

```
$ yq . service.yaml
{
  "service-1": {
    "replica": 2,
    "version": "0.6.24"
  },
  "service-2": {
    "replica": 3,
    "version": "0.21.14"
  }
}
```

Examine top level object

```
$ yq . service.yaml \
  | jq -r 'keys'
[
  "service-1",
  "service-2"
]
```

Flatten into a stream of arrays

```
$ yq . service.yaml \
  | jq -c 'keys[] as $k | .[$k] | [$k, .version, .replica]'
["service-1","0.6.24",2]
["service-2","0.21.14",3]
```

Convert to csv and format as a table

```
$ yq . service.yaml \
  | jq -cr 'keys[] as $k | .[$k] | [$k, .version, .replica] | @csv' \
  | column -s, -t
"service-1"  "0.6.24"   2
"service-2"  "0.21.14"  3
```

Add titles

```
$ yq . service.yaml \
  | jq -cr 'keys[] as $k | .[$k] | [$k, .version, .replica] | @csv' \
  | (echo '"service","version","replica"'; cat -) \
  | column -s, -t
"service"    "version"  "replica"
"service-1"  "0.6.24"   2
"service-2"  "0.21.14"  3
```

If you want no quotes around the strings in the final rows this may be better

```
$ yq . service.yaml \
  | jq -cr 'keys[] as $k | .[$k] | "\($k),\(.version),\(.replica)"' \
  | (echo '"service","version","replica"'; cat -) \
  | column -s, -t
"service"  "version"  "replica"
service-1  0.6.24     2
service-2  0.21.14    3
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your complete answer, just there is an error: ' Error: unknown command "." for "yq"
Run 'yq --help' for usage.
"service"  "version"  "replica" '

Comment: and the point is unfortunately according to the feature of my project, convert .yaml file to Json is not allowed, so I just can use 'read'option for 'yq' command

Comment: It seems our versions of `yq` differ - glad you can adapt this to work with your version.